# SQL Using record variables

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, key, unnest

I want to calculate sum of a column that stored in record variable. Here my variables types and information:

[image]

I want to find sum of the properties.value.float_value where properties.key is equal to "revenue". my table name is "userevents".

How can I conduct this in SQL(bigquery)?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Do you want the sum *per row* or across *all rows*.

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(p.value.float_value) as float_value_sum
from `userevents`
left join unnest(properties) p
where p.key = 'revenue'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a scalar subquery where you get the partial `SUM` for each row, and then an outer `SUM` to aggregate all rows:

```
WITH sample_row as (
    SELECT [
        STRUCT(
            STRUCT(
                3.14 as float_value,
                "foo" as string_value,
                16 as int_value
            ) as value,
            "revenue" as key
        ),
        STRUCT(
            STRUCT(
                1.23 as float_value,
                "bar" as string_value,
                12 as int_value
            ) as value,
            "revenue" as key
        ),
        STRUCT(
            STRUCT(
                6.66 as float_value,
                "baz" as string_value,
                99 as int_value
            ) as value,
            "stuff" as key
        )
    ] as properties
)
SELECT SUM(
    (SELECT SUM(p.value.float_value) FROM UNNEST(properties) as p WHERE p.key = "revenue")
)
FROM sample_row
```